# Kwin, xdotool, and wmctrl

Tags: xorg, kde, window-manager, xdotool

I have been trying to do something similar to what described in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9iwrew/custom_tiling_in_plasma/) and create commands to arrange windows in KDE beyond the quicktile functions currently available. I love them, but they are a bit limited when dealing with ultrawide monitors.

I've explored multiple approaches using `xdotool` and `wmctrl`, and they all work well, except they fail when the windows to be modified have have been quicktiled. Basically, Kwin does changes some property of these windows that make them insensitive to any of the above commands.

`xwininfo` does not show any differences before and after quicktiling, so it must be something more subtle.

I've tried every single option I could think about, so now I'm lost.
Any suggestions?